# Can i carry PHP variables over into an HTML or Javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, html, variables

I'm new to PHP and am trying to create an Age Validation form that will limit access to specific content on a site if a user is under a certain age.

This is the HTML form (index.html):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="data.php" method="POST">
      <input type="date" name="date" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is the PHP script(data.php):

```html
<?php  //Age Validation Form
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { //Check if button clicked on form page

   $date2=date("Y-m-d");//today's date

   $date1=new DateTime($_REQUEST['date']); //user date
   $date2=new DateTime($date2);

   $interval = $date1->diff($date2); //check diff between dates

   $myage= $interval->y; //resulting age

  if ($myage >= 16){  //full access to website is granted
     $_SESSION[$limited] = false;
     header('Location: ../index.php');
   }else{ //limited access is granted
      $_SESSION[$limited] = true;
     header('Location: ../index.php');
   }

  }else{ //if result page page is loaded without form submission
      echo "Return to start page";
  }

  ?>

   <form action="index.html"> <!--Return to form page-->
      <button type="submit">Return</button>
   </form>
```

I would like to be able and carry the resulting $limited variable from the PHP file into this HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction () {
            var access = <?php echo $limited ?>;

            var txt = document.createElement('h1');
            txt.innerHTML = access;
            document.body.appendChild(txt);
        }

        myFunction();


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is currently just for testing to make sure it can carry over. I have tried the $_SESSION method but i can't seem to figure it out.

Any and all possible solutions welcomed.

Thank you

Comment: Where is `$limited` defined?

Comment: $limited would be defined in data.php depending on the user input. it is defined as 'false' if the user age is over 16, and defined as 'true' if the user age is less than or equal to 16. i would then like to carry over that value into home.html to dictate what content is available to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your HTML file must be parsed by the PHP interpreter so it must have the .php extension in order to access any session variable.

Here's an example with 3 files in the same directory based on your question:

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="data.php" method="POST">
      <input type="date" name="date" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**data.php:**

```php
<?php  //Age Validation Form
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { //Check if button clicked on form page

   $date2=date("Y-m-d");//today's date

   $date1=new DateTime($_REQUEST['date']); //user date
   $date2=new DateTime($date2);

   $interval = $date1->diff($date2); //check diff between dates

   $myage= $interval->y; //resulting age

  if ($myage >= 16){  //full access to website is granted
     $_SESSION['limited'] = false;
     header('Location: new.php');
   }else{ //limited access is granted
      $_SESSION['limited'] = true;
     header('Location: new.php');
   }

  }else{ //if result page page is loaded without form submission
      echo "Return to start page";
  }

  ?>

   <form action="index.html"> <!--Return to form page-->
      <button type="submit">Return</button>
   </form>
```

**new.php**(the new page, where you access your session variable)

```php
<?php 
session_start();

$limited = $_SESSION['limited'] ?? true;

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction () {
            var access = <?php echo $limited ? "true" : "false" ?>;

            var txt = document.createElement('h1');
            txt.innerHTML = access;
            document.body.appendChild(txt);
        }

        myFunction();


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, thank you. this worked. i knew that if i was using $_SESSION i needed my "results" page needed to also have the .php extension (i should have mentioned). my issue was being unable to carry over the value (based on user input )of the $limited variable. But this has achieved exactly what i was looking for. Thank you for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

You're using $limited as a key in the $_SESSION array. What's in $limited ?
I'm pretty sure that if you reassign the correct value to $limited, you can access the value in $_SESSION with this:

```
    <?php $limited = 'MyAwesomeKey'; ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
      </head>
      <body>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            function myFunction () {
                var access = <?php echo $_SESSION[$limited] ?>;
                var txt = document.createElement('h1');
                txt.innerHTML = access;
                document.body.appendChild(txt);
            }
            myFunction();
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: $limited would be defined in data.php, depending on user input, it either has a value of true or false. Since it is dependant on user input, it's not hard-defined. My issue is carry that value over to the home.html after it's been defined after user input.
i am quite new to PHP so i might be missing certain obvious things, and for that i apologize